# Search within navigation properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-code-first

I have created my application by using code-first approach in ASP.NET MVC 4.

I have three entities. Namely, "Company", "Service" and "ServiceFeature":

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Service SuppliedService { get; set; }

}

public class Service
{
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ServiceFeature> ServiceFeatures { get; set; }

}    

public class ServiceFeature
{
    public int ServiceFeatureID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }


}
```

I have a search form, it consists of checkboxes for all ServiceFeatures. User will select checkboxes and get the results of Companies that are providing the Services with selected ServiceFeatures.

I get the Company list with my service as below but I'm stuck at how to include the selected ServiceFeatures in a where clause  (dynamic LINQ with a for loop?)

```
var searchResults = _companyService.GetCompanies();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a collection containing the IDs of the selected features, called `requested`, and assuming you want the companies supplying a service which contains ALL the selected features, you could for example do this:

```
var q = from c in searchResults
        let sf = c.SuppliedService.ServiceFeatures
                                  .Select(f => f.ServiceFeatureID)
                                  .Intersect(requested)
        where sf.Count() == requested.Count()
        select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

In similar cases I prefer an approach that's a bit more elaborate than a linq query with `Intersect`. `Intersect` can produce horrible queries with deep nesting, because the list with Id values to intersect over is built by `SELECT` and `UNION` commands for each Id in the list. This is not a problem when the number of Id's is low (true in your case, I assume), but with larger numbers it may throw a SQL exception.

So this is what I'd prefer:

```
var q = context.Companies.AsQueryable();

foreach(int i in featureIds)
{
    int j = i; // prevent modified closure.
    q = q.Where(c => c.SuppliedService.ServiceFeatures.Any(f => f.Id == j));
}

var result = q.ToList();
```

It builds a query with a number of `WHERE EXISTS` clauses. This can be very efficient because each `EXISTS` will seek (not scan) the primary index of `ServiceFeature`. Besides that, an `INTERSECT` is an implicit `DISTINCT`.

Well, just wanted to point this out. As said, with low numbers of records you won't notice any difference. So take whatever suits you best.